# PHP SoapServer handle no attributes

Tags: php, attributes, handle, soapserver

I try to build a simple WebService using soapServer but I have a problem with attributes.
I have build the simplest Server:

server.php

```
$request        = file_get_contents("php://input");
$soapServer     = new SoapServer(NULL, array('uri' => $wsdlPath));
$soapServer->addFunction('TestFunction');
$soapServer->handle($request);
function TestFunction($request){
   return $request;
}
```

and i use SoapUi to check the $request after the handling of soapServer.

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ind:Authorization>
         <Username>testUser</Username>
         <Password>testPass</Password>
      </ind:Authorization>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <TestFuntion>
            <TestFuntionRQ>
                <Books>
                    <Book Quantity="2">This is a test Book</Book>
                </Books>    
            </TestFuntionRQ>
        </TestFuntion>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i get Back as a response (request after handling of the soapServer):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <TestFunctionResponse>
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
            <Books xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
               <Book xsi:type="xsd:string">This is a test Book</Book>
            </Books>
         </return>
      </TestFunctionResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Making a vardump i get:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["Books"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
    ["Book"]=>
    string(19) "This is a test Book"
  }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1) why soapServer does not keep the information of the attributes after handling?

2) Is there any way to keep $request 'untouched' after $soapServer->handle($request). I mean is there any option to get $request in another type (for example plain string) instead of object(stdClass) after the handling?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to find an answer but I couldn't find a similar post. Does SoapServer's handle not support attributes?